# Parse XSLT with DOMParser

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, domparser

I know one can parse XML like that:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
```

But can we also parse XSLT?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: As you earlier said you want to load the XSLT from the server note that `XMLHttpRequest` normally directly popupates the `responseXML` property if you load an XML or XSLT document, in that case there is no need to feed e.g. `responseText` to `DOMParser`, you directly have the already parsed document as the `responseXML`.

Comment: Yes but I don't want to use a `XMLHttpRequest`, in fact the XSLT code will be directly in the HTML file inside a `<script>` tag.

Comment: It might be useful to explain what you are actually trying to achieve. Apart from anything else, we get lots of question on StackOverflow from people who misuse the word "parse", so we can never quite be sure it is being used correctly.

Comment: What I want to achieve is an application that executes a XSL transformation using the `XSLTProcessor`. The application must be condensed in 1 HTML file so the XSL code must be stored in it somehow, I won't use a `XMLHttpRequest` to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, XSLT is nothing else than XML. So you can simply do this:

```
const xslDoc = parser.parseFromString(xslStr, "text/xml");
```